# UDP socket connect, disconnect, and reconnect

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming, udp, connection

I am doing my homework and my professor said I need to establish a connection on UDP which I can not understand why do this because I thought UDP doesn't need to establish a connection.

Also, I need to disconnect when the client received all data from the server.
Then I need to reconnect to send data to the server again.

I'm using python and I wonder if I write code like this

**Client side**

```
client.close() //is it right to disconnect? 
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) // is it right to reconnect?
```

Am I following right direction that professor expects?

Comment: Both the professor and the naming in the `socket` are a bit misleading. UDP does not need a "connection" or "socket" as TCP does. One side listens to a UDP port and the other sends a datagram to it. (There can be multiple senders and datagrams.) For detailed help on your code show it to us completely and ask a specific question!

Comment: @KlausD. UDP does need a socket.

Comment: Your professor apparently wants you to issue `connect()` on the UDP socket. When you do that, you can use `read()` and `write()` and `send()` and `recv()`, as the socket knows what the remote IP address & port are. This does not create a network connection: it just conditions the local API.

Comment: To disconnect a UDP socket, call `connect()` again with a null socket-address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, UDP doesn't have *connections* in the normal sense, so it's hard to know what exactly your professor had in mind. The best course of action therefore would be to just ask them.

But if I had to guess, they either want you to:

1. call `connect()` on the socket or
2. establish some sort of "logical" connection at the application level.

Calling `connect()` on a UDP socket doesn't do any actual I/O, but it does tell the socket who the destination is. This allows you to send data using `send()` as opposed to `sendto()`.

If your prof meant option (2), then it's probably just about having an information exchange between two endpoints. So although there's no connection at the protocol layer, the two endpoints talk to each other and are therefore *connected*.

Comment: I actually got this question after asking the professor some descriptions on the homework, and I think she was meant option(2).  Thank you for helping me understand!!!